# AngularJS with JSP

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I am new to AngularJS.I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to use JSP pages instead of HTML in AngularJS.
2. Is it possible to create a web application using AngularJS without webservices (for fetching data from DB) and use HTTP servlet for that purpose

Comment: Welcome to SO..... [Please read this instruction before asking any question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Why would you want to use JSP instead of Angular HTML directives? Or, what would you use Angular for if you want to build a web app using JSP?

Comment: @prtnkl We are revamping existing application which has JSP pages . I wanted to know whether it is possible to use the existing JSP instead of writing new HTML

Comment: So you should be able to do it. But I'd rather build my app from scratch with Angular if I could choose (unless it is enough complex to make its creation with Angular difficult).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use JSP pages instead of HTML in AngularJS.

Even if you use JSP the final output will be HTML so you can use JSP in AngularJS but JSP files are mainly used to render the frontend with data that you can do using HTML only in AngularJS.

> Is it possible to create a web application using AngularJS without web services (for fetching data from DB) and use HTTP servlet for that purpose

Whether you use plain Servlet or any framework that creates REST APIs, it will be HTTP calls only.

Comment: Thank u so much @karthikeyan vaithilingam

Answer (score 0):

(This is a newbie question which applies equally to all front-end MVVM frameworks. I'll answer it for the general good.)

- AngularJS is a front-end framework which runs in the browser. It relies on a server delivering the content (HTML templates, CSS and JS sources) to the browser.
- What you use as a server, is entirely up to you. It depends on whether you need server-side dynamic content.
- If none is required in that area, you can use a static HTTP server like LightHTTP, or plain old apache, or nginx, or anything else to deliver the AngularJS site to the browser.
- But in most you will have some server interaction (i.e. storing / querying stuff in a database, or communication / synchronization with other users, etc). The common approach for that is to deliver HTML/CSS/JS statically and add a bunch of REST interfaces. Flask and Tornado are popular server choices for that, or stuff like spray.IO / akka.http for higher traffic volumes.
- In specific cases, you may want to work with pre-rendered HTML templates (usually because you want to dynamically exclude parts of pages for security/user role reasons). Then you need a server-side framework with template rendering. Django, JSP, ASP, pick your favourite.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking how to use AngularJs in a JavaEE application. And yes it is possible. Only your index.jsp will be in jsp, and all you other views will be in html.

You can then use http requests to fetch data through your servlets.

Answer (score 0):

it can be useful. here are scenarios:

- you want to save ram, cpu for mobile phones or machines that doesn't have lots of power. you can partially render page in jsp and keep only minimal in angular.
- your team is traditionally jsp heavy and you want to use them and gradually transfer to angular. eg... for i18n rendering jsp seems far better. note that i18n may not add lots of values in angular and you may not want to throw up existing code in jsp.
- I have been noticing strong views in stackoverflow and they seem to dismiss everything that doesn't fit in their utopian all new cutting edge. all the angular projects I worked had heavy dose of legacy pages using jsp and it doesn't make sense to rewrite everything from scratch or lay off whole team and start hiring from scratch. and thus, yes, jsp makes sense with angular.